# Relativement à, relatif à, en lien avec, lié à ou concernant?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

> Est-ce que toutes les affaires **relativement au** décès tragique de ton conjoint sont réglées? As-tu réussi à mettre un terme à tes dispositions? As-tu dorénavant la conscience tranquille?

> Est-ce que toutes les affaires **relatives au** décès tragique de ton conjoint sont réglées? As-tu réussi à mettre un terme à tes dispositions. As-tu dorénavant la conscience tranquille?

> Est-ce que toutes les affaires **en lien avec** le décès tragique de ton conjoint sont réglées? As-tu réussi à mettre un terme à tes dispositions? As-tu dorénavant la conscience tranquille?

> Est-ce que toutes les affaires **liées au** décès tragique de ton conjoint sont réglées? As-tu réussi à mettre un terme à tes dispositions? As-tu dorénavant la conscience tranquille?

> Est-ce que toutes les affaires **concernant le** décès tragique de ton conjoint sont réglées? As-tu réussi à mettre un terme à tes dispositions? As-tu dorénavant la conscience tranquille?

Comment: La première n'est probablement pas grammaticale, les quatre autres se valent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La première n'est pas grammaticale, on ne remplace pas directement un adjectif par un adverbe.

Les quatre autres se valent, bien que curieusement, la forme avec "en lien avec" ne soit pas trouvée dans Google books.

[image]

Une recherche globale via Google ne trouve que cinq occurrences de "les affaires relativement au", la plupart des XVIII<sup>e</sup> et XIX<sup>e</sup> siècles. Deux seulement ont été écrites par des francophones natifs. Une est grammaticale car ce ne sont pas les affaires qui sont relatives mais leur expédition qui est faite relativement à un système.

Answer (score -1):

Les définitions de la  première locution  et de la seconde montrent qu'elles sont synonymes et  la première locution est définie par la cinquième ; il s'ensuit que les trois sont synonymes les unes des autres.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/relativement)) **relativement**  **1.** Pour ce qui est de, en ce qui concerne. Synon. concernant, eu égard à, quant à, au sujet de

> ([relatif à](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/relatif)) A. − **Relatif à**. Qui a trait à, qui concerne (quelque chose, quelqu'un).

La troisième et la quatrième sont probablement quasi-synonymes ; si dans le TLFi, parmi les possibilités d'usage figuré il n'existe pas de cas général d'usage de « lié à » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/li%C3%A9)), la [recherche « affaires liées au »](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22affaires%20li%C3%A9es%20au%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=affaires+li%C3%A9es+au&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caffaires%20li%C3%A9es%20au%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caffaires%20li%C3%A9es%20au%3B%2Cc0)) montre que ce nouvel usage a été quasiment établi durant les trentes dernières années et qu'il correspond à l'usage de « en lien avec ».

« Être en lien avec qqc » signifie « être en relation » avec qqc ([André Racicot](https://andreracicot.ca/en-lien/))

Le problème dans ce choix est donc de savoir si « affaires au sujet de quelque chose « revient strictement à dire « affaires en lien avec quelque chose » ; je ne crois pas que ce soit le cas. Par exemple, dans une fraude par détournement de fonds qui ont été investi dans un organisme non impliqué dans la fraude, mais qui est soumis à des procédures de restitution, cette conséquence peut être dite liée à la fraude, mais il ne semble pas que l'on puisse dire qu'elle ens fait  partie ; l'affaire des  décisions légales à l'encontre de cet organisme ne semble pas faire partie du sujet qu'et la fraude elle-même.

Selon ce point de vue, c'est à dire qu'il s'agirait de deux groupes de locutions suffisamment différents l'un de l'autre pour devoir faire un choix entre eux en fonction de ce que l'on tient à exprimer, dans chacun des deux groupes les éléments sont équivalents et le choix peut être une simple question de pile ou face.

---

*Additions d'exemples tirés des Livres Google qui montrent que « relativement » est parfois employé en tant que modificateur d'un groupe verbal, en particulier au Canada (en contradiction du principe grammatical actuel selon lequel ne sont concevables que trois sortes de modifications, celle d'un verbe, d'un adjectif et d'un autre adverbe*

([réf. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/M%C3%A9moire_%C3%A0_la_Commission_parlementaire/VRZSzQEACAAJ?hl=fr))
Mémoire à la Commission parlementaire de la culture relativement à la politique culturelle

([réf. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Ecole_Nationale_d_Agriculture_de_Montpel/_IxTswEACAAJ?hl=fr)) Ecole Nationale d'Agriculture de Montpellier. Conseils Aux Viticulteurs Relativement Tome1: À La Reconstitution Des Vignobles Par Les Vignes Américain

([réf. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Cons%C3%A9quences_Des_Condamnations_P%C3%A9nales/rMhADQEACAAJ?hl=fr))
Conséquences Des Condamnations Pénales Relativement À l'État Et La Capacité Des Personnes

([réf. 4](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/D%C3%A9nonciation_Aux_Cours_Royales_Relative/30Y6jgEACAAJ?hl=fr))
Dénonciation Aux Cours Royales, Relativement Au Système Religieux Et Politique

([réf. 5](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Th%C3%A8se_de_Doctorat_de_l_Absence_Relative/IxnHvAEACAAJ?hl=fr))
Thèse de Doctorat. de l'Absence Relativement Au Conjoint Présent. 30 Octobre 1900

([réf. 6, 1958, Canada](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Rapport_relativement_%C3%A0_l_enqu%C3%AAte_deman/m0UwMwEACAAJ?hl=fr))
Rapport ... relativement à l'enquête demandée par le ministre des Finances sur la fluorine (spath fluor) [10 septembre 1958].

([réf. 7](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Tendances_actuelles_en_Allemagne_relativ/_axhQwAACAAJ?hl=fr))
Tendances actuelles en Allemagne relativement à l'emploi de l'artillerie lourde en campagne

([réf. 8, 1991 Canada](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Canada_Gazette/3kxKAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22relativement%22&dq=%22relativement%22&printsec=frontcover))
formuler une opinion en application du sous-alinéa (l)ò)(iii) relativement aux personnes suivantes : a) le conjoint du répondant qui n'a aucune personne

([réf. 9, Canada](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_f%C3%A9d%C3%A9ralisme_et_la_soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_canadie/GXwHAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22relativement%22&dq=%22relativement%22&printsec=frontcover))
Il ne faudrait pas non plus se fier à l ' intervention fédérale : le sort de la « loi réparatrice » de 1896 , relativement aux écoles du Manitoba , nous a

([réf. 10, Canada](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Minutes_of_Proceedings_and_Evidence/l-gKAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22relativement%22&dq=%22relativement%22&printsec=frontcover)) C'est à la page 23 du rapport relativement à la situation des produits forestiers, et c'est plutôt une question de renseignements